# (SPRING) get user's information from postgresql database and print in thymeleaf html

Tags: java, html, spring, postgresql, thymeleaf

i'm currently using SPRING, and i want to print out user's detail from the database (i'm using postgresql) to an HTML page (thymeleaf based template), is there any way to do that from my Controller class, and how to print it on HTML Thymeleaf page?

here's the detail of my code:

Controller Class,

```
package com.owlexa.cms.web.controller;
// ...
import com.owlexa.cms.dto.UsersDto;
import com.owlexa.cms.model.Role;
import com.owlexa.cms.model.Users;
import com.owlexa.cms.search.UserSearchParams;
import com.owlexa.cms.service.UserService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/case")
@SessionAttributes("searchParamSession")
public class CaseController extends BaseController {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('" + ACLConstant.MENU_CASE_PAYMENT + "','" + ACLConstant.MENU_CASE_ACTIVECASE + "')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchCase", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String searchpayment(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "case/searchCase";
    }
}
```

here's my html page

```
<tr>
  <td><label>Provider Name </label></td>
  <td><label>:</label></td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="**(GET USER FIRST NAME ?)**" style="width:275px;" readonly="readonly">
  </td>
</tr>
```

thx in advance, if u need another details, i will update it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you implement [UserDetails](https://web.archive.org/web/20161009044824/http://docs.spring.io:80/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) interface and that class has property like `firstName`:

```html
<input type="text" data-th-value="${#request.userPrincipal.principal.firstName}">
```